How to limit bucket upload size in Backblaze B2 (S3 COMPATIBLE API)?
I'm implementing a functionality in our app where users buy a subscription and create their workspace. Each subscription plan has different storage limits (e.g, 5 GB for a small plan). We use Backblaze B2 for storage, and currently, we create a separate bucket whenever an organization is created, which works fine.
However, I need to limit the bucket upload size according to the subscription plan the user has purchased. I have researched a lot but couldnt find a way to enforce storage limits on Backblaze buckets. Moreover, Backblaze doesn't seem to offer a way to get the storage size of a bucket or a whole folder.
I have gone through Backblaze documentation and searched online for any existing solutions or workarounds but haven't found a way to directly limit the storage size of a bucket. I expected to find a method or API that allows setting storage quotas or retrieving the total size of a bucket to enforce these limits programmatically.
Additionally, I'm using @aws-sdk/client-s3 for managing S3-compatible storage.
Does anyone know how to implement storage limits on Backblaze B2 buckets based on the user's subscription plan? Any advice or workarounds would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Amazon S3 does not offer this functionality, so it would either need to be a feature of Backblaze or something that your code manages.

You are right. Therefore, I handle it in my code by summing the file sizes upon upload and storing this total in the database. I also verify if the total exceeds the plan size limit. Thanks for the help Man.

You can achieve your goal using the Backblaze Partner API. Rather than creating a bucket per customer in a single Backblaze account, you can use the Partner API to create Backblaze accounts, under your control, and organized into groups, for your customers.
The group member account does not allow the customer to log in; instead, you, as the group admin, can create an application key for the group member and perform operations in the context of that account.
You can also set caps on storage, download bandwidth, etc, per account, and access daily reports detailing usage of each of your group members.
The Partner API docs list the steps to get started. In particular, note that you will need to contact Backblaze sales for them to enable access to the API for you.

you will have to create a route yourself with multer to accept the file, then in your route you can validate the file type/size etc. and upload it from there

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
